# How To Make visible a button only when a div clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".col-sm-4.righPanelRobotIcons").click(function () {
      $("#Schedule").show();
   });
});
```

Here `.col-sm-4.righPanelRobotIcons` is A generic div class.When I click the div I want to show a button which has **Schedule** as Button id and initially hidden visibility. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: What is wrong with that?

Comment: showing button when we click div

Comment: @newman  Don"t know it was unable to click

Comment: How do you hide the `#Schedule`?

Comment: By giving Visibility:hidden in css

Comment: Create working stack snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `display: none;` on your css to hide your button.

```js
$(".col-sm-4.righPanelRobotIcons").click(function() {
  $("#Schedule").show();
});
```

```css
.righPanelRobotIcons {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

#Schedule {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-4 righPanelRobotIcons"></div>
<button type="button" id="Schedule">Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have class "hide" attached to that button, then do this

```
$(".col-sm-4.righPanelRobotIcons").click(function () {
     $("#Schedule").removeClass("hide");
});
```

.show() works only when you give css property display:none, for visibility:hidden, you have to change css to visibility:visible on click

```
$(".col-sm-4.righPanelRobotIcons").click(function () {
     $("#Schedule").css("visibility", "visible");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have HTML getting generated dynamically, you might have to use jquery `on` event.

Can you try something like the snippet below :

```
  $(".col-sm-4.righPanelRobotIcons").on("click",function () {
            $("#Schedule").show();
  });
```

```js
$(".col-sm-4.righPanelRobotIcons").on("click", function() {
  $("#Schedule").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-4 righPanelRobotIcons"> Click Me!
  <button type="Button" id="Schedule" style="display:none">Schedule</button>

</div>
```